# json key gets assigned a number instead of array when second element is supposed to be pushed

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to generate a JSON object which I expect to look like this:

```
{
 "sreddy-vm-1":["MyDatabase-1"],
 "sreddy-vm-2":["MyDatabase-2"], 
 "sreddy-vm-3":["MyDatabase-3", "MyDatabase-4", "MyDatabase-5"]
}
```

but its generating this instead

```
{"sreddy-vm-1":["MyDatabase-1"],"sreddy-vm-2":["MyDatabase-2"], "sreddy-vm-3":3}
```

The correct json is generated until the point at which each key has one element in the array, the moment second element is added to the array for `sreddy-vm-3` it assigns 2 and then in the next(last) loop it ends up assigning 3.
I can't figure out whats going on. I'm new to Javascript in general.Please help. Thank you!

**Code**

```
// part of the code
$scope.forests = ["MyDatabase-1", "MyDatabase-2", "MyDatabase-3", "MyDatabase-4", "MyDatabase-5"];
$scope.forestsOnHosts = {};
angular.forEach($scope.forests, function(forest, key){
    $scope.forestsOnHosts[host] = function () {
        if ($scope.forestsOnHosts[host] === undefined || $scope.forestsOnHosts[host] === null) {
            console.log('******************');
            return new Array(forest);
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.forestsOnHosts[host]));
            var arr = new Array($scope.forestsOnHosts[host]);
            return arr.push(forest);
        }
    }.call();
}
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.forestsOnHosts));
```

Comment: what is host in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return arr.push(forest);
```

this does **not** return an array, as you might expect.

```
arr.push(forest);
return arr;
```